# UACC-462 cell culture

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

[UACC-462 is a pancreatic cell line established in the University of Arizona Cancer Center (UACC)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC323906/pdf/pnas00318-0176.pdf).
[The cells are available from ATCC and there is the instruction for culturing UACC-462.](http://www.atcc.org/Products/All/CRL-2989.aspx#culturemethod)

M-41 medium. The base medium for this cell line is ATCC-formulated Leibovitz's 
L-15 Medium, Catalog No. 30-2008. To make the complete growth medium, add the following components to the base medium (final conc.):

fetal bovine serum to a final concentration of 5%

0.01 mg/ml transferrin

0.01 mg/ml insulin

5 µg/ml (55 U/ml) catalase

3.6 µg/ml (0.01 mM) hydrocortisone

10 ng/ml EGF

3 ng/ml Estradiol

70 µg/ml O-phosphorylethanilamine

0.0008 µg/ml L-thyroxine

extra 2mM L-glutamine

Atmosphere: air, 95%; carbon dioxide (CO2), 5%.
Temperature: 37°C

[On the other hand, L-15 is designed to culture without CO2](http://www.atcc.org/Products/All/30-2008.aspx) and often used time-laps experiments under microscope.

My question is why L-15 based media can be used in CO2 incubator. Is the cell line acid-philic?

Comment: There are a number of cancer cell lines that are grown in various forms of L-15 in 5% $CO_2$ incubators. I don't know the exact biochemistry behind it, but it works, so that's what's used.

Comment: @MattDMo Regarding this cell line, an ATCC technician admitted the mistake. Do you have experiences culturing cancer cells with L-15 based media in 5% CO2? I would like to know which cells can be grown under the condition, for future reference.

Comment: unfortunately, I am no longer at the lab where they did this, so I can't check the database. So, ATCC said the line *shouldn't* be cultured with $CO_2$?

Comment: @MattDMo "It should read 100% atmospheric conditions." That's what they said.

Comment: @MattDMo May I post another question to ask cells that can be grown with L-15 based media in 5%CO2?

Comment: I suppose you could, but it seems like a fairly narrow question. I'd do some good googling for a while to learn the history of L-15 and see if you can find some lists on your own. A lot of labs post their protocols online, so you may find something there.